# Restart spring boot application using actuator in wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to use Spring Boot Actuator to restart the spring to update its newest properties.

I followed this tutorial:
https://javapointers.com/spring/spring-boot/how-to-restart-spring-boot-automatically-using-actuator/

So what I did is just to add the properties

```
management.endpoint.restart.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=restart,health
```

and call the endpoint

```
{host}/actuator/restart
```

I tested it on my local using the embedded tomcat server, and it works.

But when I tried it in jboss/wildfly, because my client are using it for their production server, it doesn't work.

This is the error that I got:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties': Could not bind properties to 'ServerProperties' : prefix=server, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3aa3a991 has been closed already
```

Please let me know if there is something else that I need to provide.

Comment: How do you restart the app? Can you provide us some code?

Comment: Hi @Pilpo, I have added the guide that I followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You could take a look at Spring Cloud Config to solve properly your problem : [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_quick_start)

It allow you to externalize properties, manage them and expose them to clients (like your application).

And it has some benefits like 'No restart needed'

Comment: I think it still need to restart/refresh the config right? I checked some links about that, and it seems the restart/refresh from actuator is still needed.

https://www.devglan.com/spring-cloud/refresh-property-config-runtime

Btw, thanks for this. I tried using refresh, and it works in wildfly. So I think I will go with that path instead.

Just curious why the restart doesn't work in wildfly..